# How to change time in datetime python and add a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-module

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1)
t = datetime.time(12, 34)
final = datetime.datetime.combine(dt.date(), t)
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
  print(final)
```

I want to make it repeat over and over with the time changing but I keep printing the same time over and over, the time isn't changing

Comment: `final` will change only if you will move `final = datetime.datetime.combine(dt.date(), t) into the loop body
`

Comment: @balderman checked it it still dosen't work

Comment: how do you want "the time changing"? increment it? by?

Comment: @MrFuppes ?????

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "change". do you want to show the current time or do you want to replace one of the attributes of the datetime object? have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)...

Comment: @MrFuppes I want the time to keep changing but the time isn't changing it just keep showing the same time over and over again

Comment: sure, because you assign a specific datetime object to your variable `final` - what makes you think that will automagically change its value? You'll have to update it in each iteration of the loop if you want it to hold a different date and time.

Comment: ohh, I opps sry. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

an illustration of my comments; what you could do

```
from datetime import datetime

t0 = datetime(2020,9,18,0,0,0)

for i in range(5):
    print(t0.replace(hour=i+1))
    
# prints
# 2020-09-18 01:00:00
# 2020-09-18 02:00:00
# 2020-09-18 03:00:00
# 2020-09-18 04:00:00
# 2020-09-18 05:00:00
```

Comment: Dat only change hour?

Comment: @IronBot9992: jep, but you could modify it to change what ever attribute you want, e.g. day, month, etc. Have a look at the docs and play around with it to find out ;-)